# bib file is not recognized

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using a [template](http://www.degruyter.com/view/supplement/s20814836_LaTeX_Template.zip) from this [journal](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pjbr). In this template the bibliography part is written inside the tex file. I would like to use my own `bib` file. I tried the following lines at the end of the tex file bedore the `\end{document}` but it doesn't recognize the bib file:

```
\bibliographystyle{dgruyter_author}
\bibliography{Mybib}
```

I have added some citation in the middle of the text `\cite` I checked the warning I get is:

`Package natbib warning: Citation "Brown1997High" on page 1 undefined.`

- The bib file is in the main folder of the template files beside the main tex file.
- I have used the bib file with other styles for instance IEEE, ... before.
- I am using `winedt8.1` on `windows`

What should I do?

**Update:** if I change the code to:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Mybib}
```

it works. But now the question is: How can I use the style from the template?
A copy of the style file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/WsUm9nX5).

As you asked I add the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%(only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_author}
\begin{document}
\articletype{Research Article{\hfill}Open Access}
\author*[1]{Corresponding Author}
\affil[1]{Affil, E-mail: email@email.edu}
\title{\huge Article title}
\runningtitle{Article title}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\paragraph{Reference to a standard}
Elements to cite:
Standard symbol and number,
Title \cite{standard-1}.
% >>>>> I replaced the following lines >>>>>
%\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%\bibitem{standard-2} ISO/TR 9544:1988, Information processing --- Computer-assisted publishing --- Vocabulary
%\end{thebibliography}

% >>>>> with these lines >>>>>>>
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Mybib}

\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the `sty` file, maybe it is useful. The problem is that it works with `\bibliographystyle{plain}` but the style is different from the other parts of the `tex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I rename your style file `dgruyter.sty` to `dgruyter_author.sty` and add the missing logo `dg-degruyter.png` (it is called in the style file!) into the same directory and add a bib file with package `filecontents` into your MWE it compiles for me with two warnings comming from the style file..

The new MWE is:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{billingsley,
  title     = {Convergence of Probability Measures},
  author    = {P. Billingsley},
  year      = {1968},
  publisher = {Wiley, New York},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%(only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)

%\usepackage[big]{dgruyter} % throws two warnings
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_author} % file dgruyter.sty -> dgruyter_author.sty
\begin{document}
\articletype{Research Article{\hfill}Open Access}
\author*[1]{Corresponding Author}
\affil[1]{Affil, E-mail: email@email.edu}
\title{\huge Article title}
\runningtitle{Article title}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\paragraph{Reference to a standard}
Elements to cite:
Standard symbol and number,
Title \cite{billingsley}.
% >>>>> I replaced the following lines >>>>>
%\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%\bibitem{standard-2} ISO/TR 9544:1988, Information processing --- Computer-assisted publishing --- Vocabulary
%\end{thebibliography}

% >>>>> with these lines >>>>>>>
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Please try this new MWE and tell us if it shows the result you want.